# Bonno WordPress Theme Caching CSS updates indefinitely

Tags: wordpress, css, caching, wordpress-theming

Recently I purchased a WordPress Theme called "Bonno" (http://bonno.aisconverse.com/). It's a great theme, but there seems to be one major drawback: Anytime you make a stylistic change to the style.css (via the Appearance --> Editor), the update will not occur.

I've tried:

- Shift + R on a browser
- Installing a plugin to clear the cache (WP Super Cache)
- Making a post on a completely different page via Post/Update (this
  sometimes works, other times does not -- not sure how or why)

Has anyone else encountered similar issues on Bonno? Or any other WordPress themes?

Comment: Correct WP link: http://bonnowp.aisconverse.com/

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem your can add extra string right after the filename using a `?` character.
Edit the theme file to change the link tag.

**Example-**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css?123">
```

However it gets static and next time if you change the CSS again you might not get the update instantly. For this, you can use PHP to add the string dynamically by using `time()` function.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css?<?php echo time(); ?>">
```

And now you can get instant update of your changes. This will not affect your CSS file.

Comment: Will this not be overwritten when the theme updates? If so, I'm guessing it'll require a child theme.

Comment: Edits to your style.css will also be overwritten when you update the theme.

Comment: Yes, any customization should be placed in the child theme.